# Add a value to a column in data frame all rows at once :Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following data from df

```
   proid  sku  qty 
0  p009  SKPK  0.0  
1  p009  SKKP  2.0  
2  p008  SKPK  0.0  
3  p008  SKC1  4.0  
4  p008  SKKP  0.0
```

To qty column i want to add value to 'qty' based on value in 'sku'. the value are present as follows

```
starterkit = {"SKKP":4,'SKP1':3,'SKP1':3,'SKPK':1,'SKC1':1 }
```

want to do something like

```
if df.sku == 'SKKP' df.qty += starterkit['SKKP']
```

Resulting data frame should be

```
   proid  sku  qty 
0  p009  SKPK  1.0  
1  p009  SKKP  6.0  
2  p008  SKPK  1.0  
3  p008  SKC1  5.0  
4  p008  SKKP  4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
starterkit = {"SKKP":4,'SKP1':3,'SKP1':3,'SKPK':1,'SKC1':1 }
df.qty += df.sku.map(starterkit)
print (df)
  proid   sku  qty
0  p009  SKPK  1.0
1  p009  SKKP  6.0
2  p008  SKPK  1.0
3  p008  SKC1  5.0
4  p008  SKKP  4.0
```

Comment: but starter kit values are based on another column values in data frame

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['qty'] += df['sku'].map(starterkit)
```

This is an example of a vectorised calculation. A principle benefit of using `pandas` is the ability to perform such calculations without resorting to Python-level loops.